# JS: Replace one tag with another

Tags: javascript, html

For example, I have the following markup:

```html
<div>
  <div class="article">
    <h2></h2>
    <a href="">
      <figure>
        <img src="" /></figure>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tell me, please, how with the **native** javascript, replace `img` tags with `amp-img` tags?

In fact, my markup is much larger and has different classes. And i want to replace tags absolutely everywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: As noted in the dupe, there is no way to do this without losing listeners on the original nodes.